# Segmentation fault related to component of derived type

Tags: fortran, gfortran

As the title suggests, I'm getting a seg fault related to use of a derived type component.  This is a followup to [Segmentation fault for array, but only if a component of a derived type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986069/segmentation-fault-for-array-but-only-if-a-component-of-a-derived-type) but represents a more realistic use case.  In contrast to the prior question, there is no issue of lack of explicit interface (the example below is a single program with no subroutines, and results are the same if the program is modularized in a more realistic use case).

```
! gfortran 4.8.5 on Red Hat linux
! default compile with no extra flags:  "gfortran source.f90"
! default stack size = 8mb (ulimit -s)

program main

    type table
        real :: col(2100000) = 0.0         ! but OK if no initial value
    end type table

    type(table) :: table1(2)               ! but OK if not an array

    table1(1)%col = 1.0                    ! segfault here

end program main
```

In a more realistic use case (and in my actual one), the type `table` would defined in a module, I just combined it all in the same place for conciseness.  (I did test it this way (with the type definition in a module) and the exact same seg fault occurred.)

There are at least 3 changes here that eliminate the segfault (only the last of which works very well for my purposes)

1. Don't initialize the type
2. Don't declare `table1` as an array
3. Make the component `col` allocatable

The key (and most surprising thing to me) seems to be that it is declaring `table1` as an array that seems to fool the compiler in some way here.  Also, being a component of a derived type is an essential aspect.

For an answer I'm just looking for a general explanation of what is happening here (including if this is some kind of bug) and general recommendations on avoiding this problem -- in particular, what are the best practices to follow here that would hopefully help me avoid this issue.

Note that this issue in part relates to the stack size (e.g. `ulimit -s`) and shell interaction, but that is addressed pretty well in the answer to the preceding question and I'm hoping to examine other aspects of the issue here -- which is not to minimize that issue, but rather to also include other aspects.

**Edit to add:** @Steve comments that "This has absolutely nothing to do with Fortran let alone gfortran".  This is maybe the crux of my question.  I'd expect a fortran compiler to be able to handle **purely static** declarations as I use here but maybe I expect too much.  Is the root issue perhaps a mis-match between the environment (i.e. ulimit -s (8mb)) and the compiler flags?  Do the compilers (gfortran or others) have no way to query the environment or figure this out automatically?

I appreciate in @ripero's answer to the predecessor question that increasing  stack size can be helpful although that's somewhat incomplete to me in the sense that the problem would not necessarily seem to be the stack size but rather **some sort of mis-match between the stack size (OS or environment level issue) and compiler options like `-fmax-stack-var-size`**?

Comment: Still, making your array allocatable or using compile flags to create the array in the heap is the way to go.

Comment: The code you show is not the code you compiled.

Comment: @Steve  Thanks and sorry about that. Typo on 2nd last line, fixed now.  I had `table(1)` but was supposed to be `table1(1)`

Comment: @JohnE,  what exactly are you trying to demonstrate?  You've found another way to exhaust your stack!  Your code compiles fine with gfortran 6.4.1, 7.3.1, 8.1.1, and 9.x and executes.  Of course, my default stack size is 1 GB.  This has absolutely nothing to do with Fortran let alone gfortran.  BTW, if you turning on optimization, then program should execute for you as DCE occurs.

Comment: @steve  I edited the question in an attempt to answer your request for clarification.  Please feel free to answer in a question in detail, if you are so inclined.  Apologies if it is a dumb question but I can tell you this is a sincere attempt to understand the root causes and what are the best practices for avoiding (not just quick fixes)

Comment: The first sentence in the answer to the previous question would be a very reasonable answer to this question - it provides a general explanation (insufficient stack, not a gfortran bug), and later in the question provides workarounds/"best practices".  What specifically are you looking for, that makes this question not a duplicate?

Comment: @IanH  I tried very hard to address this (in particular the last 2 paragraphs I added at the end).  In part I think this is an improved version of that and I think there are better answers that could be given (either here or on the previous one).  E.g. more explanation of pros/cons of larger stack and **how does the stack setting interact with various compiler flags**, which no one has specifically addressed.  But feel free to mark as a duplicate if you feel that way.  FWIW, later on I'll probably either add a bounty here or tack the code onto the end of the previous Q and delete this one.